# Which Prestashop 1.7 hook is triggered, while updating customer address at Account Page and checkout Page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Can you help me to know, which hook is triggered while updating/adding address details of customer from Account Page or checkout page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIaQm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNIbS.png)

Also, how to get the address details?
I'm using

```
    foreach ($customer->getAddresses($customer->id) as $address) {
            $addressInfo=$address;
        }

using this to get the address details but not working when I first update the address.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

actionObjectAddBefore

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

actionObjectAddAfter

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

actionObjectUpdateBefore

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

actionObjectUpdateAfter

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

actionObjectDeleteBefore

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

actionObjectDeleteAfter

Located in: /classes/ObjectModel.php

*** Your ObjectName is Address ***

And to get Addresses of a customer:

```
$this->context->customer->getAddresses()
```