# Which hook trigger when address is added or updated from the shop back-end in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

When hook is triggered when adding/updating the address from the back-end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Prestashop 1.7 hook is triggered, while updating customer address at Account Page and checkout Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141922/which-prestashop-1-7-hook-is-triggered-while-updating-customer-address-at-accou)

Answer (score 0):

There are several native hooks related to addresses,
use those if you want to interact with the Address object
right before/after it is written onto DB :

**actionObjectAddressAddAfter,
actionObjectAddressUpdateAfter,
actionObjectAddressDeleteAfter**

And/or you can use

**actionValidateCustomerAddressForm**

to perform additional validation on the address form
before it's being submitted.